# Displaying Block and floor and Room on single page using asp.net mvc

Tags: c#-4.0

I am a beginner in asp.net MVC 
 I have tblBlock,tblFloor,tblRoom table in my database. I want to display all these in a single page like when I click Block number it should show the list of the floor and when I click on floor number it should show the number of rooms. how to do this within a single page in asp.net MVC.

This my view code

```
    function GetFloors() {

        $("#tblFloor tbody tr").remove();
        console.log("Hello Javascript");
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                //url: "/RoomBooking/GetFloors",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetFloors","RoomBooking")',
                dataType: "json",
                //cache: false,
                async: "false",
                contenttype:"charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {

                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        var rows = ""
                        + ""
                                  + ' tblFloor  ' + item.Floor_No + ""

                        + "";
                        $('#tblFloor tbody').append(rows);

                    });
                },


            });
            //Prevent default behavior
            return false;
        }
```

This is my controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetFloors()
    {
        List<tblFloor> floors = new List<tblFloor>();

        floors = BlockRepsitory.GetFloors(1).ToList();

         return Json(floors, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code here and the users here will gladly help fixing the issues.

Comment: that code is not working

Comment: Perhaps someone here knows how to fix the code that is not working. But for that you have to post the code so people can have a look at it and try to find out what's wrong with it.

Comment: I added the code check it

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got a solution to this problem below is code for that solution:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            loadData();
        });

    function loadData() {

            $.ajax({
                url: "/PeopleBooking/Blocklist",

                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    var html = '';
                    $.each(result, function (key, item) {
                        html += '<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 "><a href="#"onclick="return getbyID(' + item.Block_id + ')"><section class="panel panel-featured-left panel-featured-primary "><div class="panel-body zoom"><div class="widget-summary"><div class="widget-summary-col widget-summary-col-icon"><div class="summary-icon bg-white"><img src="/assets/images/RoomImg/block.png" width = "150" height = "150" class="img-circle img-responsive"/></div></div><div class="widget-summary-col"><div class="summary"><h4 class="title">' + item.Block_name + '</h4><div class="info"><strong class="amount">' + item.Block_No + '</strong></div></div></div></div></div></div></section></a></div>';
                    });
                    $('#yes').html(html);
                },
                error: function (errormessage) {
                    alert(errormessage.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```